# Restrict the zooming to be within the window in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I am using this example:
http://bl.ocks.org/d/2206590/

The zoom function zooms within the boundaries of the svg file in Chrome and firefox.

But in IE, it covers the whole window, basically making the rest of the page useless when the map is zoomed.

Is there a way to force and restrict the zoom to be within the window in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as simple as adding a div, and putting the SVG inside it. :( Sorry for asking a question before actually trying to solve it completely.